# Giving priorities to ActionListener?

Tags: java, sockets, system-tray

I was wondering if it is possible to give priotities to listeners.

I am creating a systemtray on a programme which communicates with sockets.

As soon as I call the ServerSocket.accept() method, which will wait for a socket to connect,
my systemtray stops listening until a socket is accepted.

Is there any way to resolve this?

The systemtray has options such as debug on/off and closing the programme, so it has to communicate with the programme and also have the highest priority in listening.

Thanx in advance!

EDIT:
Here's some code.

```
public class Start {

/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args Arguments given in the commandline.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        if (args[0].equals("-v")) {
            Debugger.setDebug(true);
            Debugger.showMessage("DEBUG: ON");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: OFF");
        Debugger.setDebug(false);
    }

    if (SystemTrayCreator.canRead()) {
        SystemTrayCreator stc = new SystemTrayCreator();
        new Thread(stc).start();
    }
    Connector c = new Connector();
    new Thread(c).start();

}
}

public class Connector implements Runnable{


/** Creates a Connector-object.
 * 
 */
public Connector(){
}
static Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doJob();
        t.stop();
    }
});

/** Activates the connector.
 * 
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        t.start();
    }
}

public class SystemTrayCreator implements Runnable{


/**
 * Creates a systemtray with an icon.
 *
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    //Check whether the SystemTray is supported
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        Debugger.showMessage("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you run `accept` in a separate thread?

Comment: why dont you run them in separate threads?

Comment: I think I forgot something. I used threads now but it still doesn't work, perhaps because the class of the socketconnection uses a Timer with an ActionListener. I'll post some code.

Comment: It's working, found out that I actually don't need the timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more than one thing at a time, use threads.

In your case I would have a cached thread pool i.e. Executors.newCachedThreadPool() which first has a task which accepts connections, and also has a task to read each connection (so you can accept more connections when handling a connection)